# Supersocket не может загрузить 'System.Threading'

Tags: c#, websocket, visual-studio-2015, nuget

Необходима простейшая реализация вебсокет сервера (для получения информации через браузер (javascript)).

C помощью nuget скачал SuperSocket.WebSocket
При попытке инициализации

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer();
```

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" в SuperSocket.WebSocket.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2787.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

В чем может быть проблема? Почему не загружается файл/сборка system.threading? её ведь даже в виде файла нельзя в папку с проектом подключить через ссылки.
Это проблема библиотеки Superwebsocket или моей ос+программ и частей ?
Как устранить?

Comment: А какая версия у вашей System.Threading? А то `1.0.2787.102` выглядит как-то подозрительно.

Comment: Как посмотреть версию? она же где-то глубоко зарыта в файлах .NET framework/VS/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проект, в котором я пытался использовать `Supersocket`, `Supersocket.WebSocket` был нацелен на *.NET 3.5*. Изменил на **4.6**, перекачал все что было в nuget, добавил так-же `Supersocket.SocketEngine` (почему-то в зависимостях это не указано) проблема исчезла.